# Cannot run git pull command through php

Tags: php, git, batch-file

I am not able to pull a file remotely from git server through php. I wrote the following BAT code and am trying to execute it via php.
 the batch file git1.bat is a follows:

```
cd C:\repos\rep2 && git pull origin master 2>&1
```

the php code:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("C:\\xampp\htdocs\AS-otg\\git1.bat");
?>
```

the output I get:

[image]

However, I get the required result when I do the same directly from cmd.
[image]

I tried some other git commands like log etc. which work just fine.
I need to do this via php only... please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log` is a local command that does not need to talk with a remote host. `pull` does a `fetch` first. It seems you are running the PHP script under another user than when you run the script manually. If you run it manually you authenticate to the remote server with your SSH key and when the PHP script runs the script, the effective user does not have that SSH key to authenticate with.

Btw. you should keep in mind that a pull is not suited for being done non-interactively. When doing a pull you can easily get conflicts if the incoming changes are not fast-forward.